# Show Google Analytics in Backend of Magento

Tags: magento-1.8, google-analytics

Is there a way to show a google analytics dashboard in the backend of magento?
So we can see the most relevant data easy and don't have to go to google analytics itself.

HO used to have an extension for this. But they used GAPI. Which isn't supported anymore by Google.

It would be great if it could be loaded in a window in the backend.
[image]

We use Magento 1.8.1 CE

Comment: I Changed the question. Please remove the on hold

Answer (score 1):

There is at [least one extension](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/google-analytic-dashboard.html) allowing to do so. Please check Magento Connect for more extension.